# 'ALERT' task can be used only in on load, on validate and on change actions. Check line number : 30

Tags: zoho-deluge, deluge

```
if(assignedto == var1)
{
    var2 = value.get("id");
}
else if(assignedto != var1)
{
    alert("unable to fetch");
}
```

alert function is not working in the deluge script inside if condition is there any option for doing the alert function in the deluge

Answer (score 0):

There are some contexts where alert doesn't work. That may or may not be the case in the code above.  Try replacing the `alert` with an `info` statement to see if it will display some information.
Example code:
`info "unable to fetch: assignedto: " + assignedto;`

Also maybe change the `else if` to an `else` to fully capture every case where `assignedto == var1` is false.